# Merging attributes

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector-layer

I have added attribute information from the Overlay Layer to a set of features in the Input
Layer. However, both of  the tools that I used, 'Join by Attributes' & 'Intersection' created the (correct) combined information in a new Layer. I wish to rather update the existing Input layer where my features are. Is there an option to do this in QGIS V3.30?

Comment: Using Field calculator...? However, you don't include enough information to give an answer.

Comment: You can choose the output "Joined layer" on the bottom of the tools settings when using Join by Attributes. By default QGIS will create a new temporary layer. You could also rewrite an existing one. Is this what you are looking for?